# Reading multiple lines at time from a file

Tags: ruby

How can I read multiple lines at a time from a file in Ruby?

I tried using `each_slice(2)` and also did: `require 'enumerator'`, but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
undefined method `each_slice' for #<String:0x877d12c> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: How do you define a "line", and how are you getting this data? Is it in a string or are you reading from a file?

Comment: i thought i explained it in the title, it's in a file!!

Comment: @bytebiscuit: An error message is not helpful without the *code* you tried. Just telling us that you used `each_slice` isn't helpful because you obviously used it in the wrong way (on a string?). Your code would also have told us from which source you are trying to read.

Comment: fair enough, i didn't put enough information!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `IO` and `String` have a `lines` enumerator, which you can call `each_slice` on:

```
irb(main):004:0> STDIN.lines.each_slice(2).take(2)
a
a
b
c
=> [["a\n", "a\n"], ["b\n", "c\n"]]
```

Of course you can substitute `STDIN` with any other `IO` instance (open file). Demo with a string:

```
irb(main):005:0> "a\na\nb\nc".lines.each_slice(2).to_a
=> [["a\n", "a\n"], ["b\n", "c"]]
```

Both of these work in Ruby >= 1.8.7

Comment: @Niklas this works perfectly, however in Ruby ruby 2.0 it gives a warning: `IO#lines is deprecated; use #each_line instead`.  

So, substituting the above line by `STDIN.each_slice(2).take(2)` works instead.